# Reputations shows incorrectly

Tags: bug, reputation

In my reputation  tab there

Shows **3 events**. But **4 upvote**
[image]

Comment: It says "4 events" now. Might be caching.

Comment: Because the up vote 10 mins ago was new (unread and highlighted in yellow), and was shown separately from the rest. But if you click the triangle to expand it, it loads all the relevant events under the same post in the respective time frame.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I searched too much but couldn't find that duplicate. Not sure if you are better seeker or I need some coffee.

Comment: @hims056 perhaps both? ;)